# replace values in data.frame in R based on two vectors

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to write a GENERAL-purpose looping function that replaces *one **or more** unwanted values* (e.g., `"#N/A"` & `'p'`) in a `data.frame` with *one **or more** desired* values (e.g., `NA`) in BASE R.

I have tried the following with no success, is there an efficient fix?

```
input <- data.frame(id = c(1,3,"#N/A"), school = LETTERS[1:3], read_2018 =c("#N/A",'p',49))

replace = c("#N/A", 'p') # can be one or more elements
with = NA                # if shorter in length than `replace`, recycle the last element

# My solution without scucess:
lapply(seq_along(replace), function(i){input[input == replace[i]] <- with[i]; input})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question with `loops`, the following should work with minimal modification of your attempted solution.

```
for(i in seq_along(replace)){
  input[input == replace[i]] <- with[i]
  }

input
#    id school read_2018
#1    1      A      <NA>
#2    3      B      <NA>
#3 <NA>      C        49
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have limited `replace` values (like 2 in this case) you could do

```
input[input == replace[1] | input == replace[2]] <- with
```

However, if the `replace` value can be more or you don't want to write them one by one like this, you could use `sapply` with `%in%` to get logical values where a match is found.

```
input[sapply(input, `%in%`, replace)] <- with
input
#    id school read_2018
#1    1      A      <NA>
#2    3      B      <NA>
#3 <NA>      C        49
```